# How to make the dictionary in providing all the inputs given,not only the last updated one?

Tags: python

I am given the problem to add new employees in a dictionary.However when i am giving new values to the dictionary,previous values are not getting displayed and only the new value is showing.Please help

```
m = int(input("How many employees do you wish to enter"))
        for i in range(0,m):
            a = input('Enter Employee id')
            b = input('Enter name')
            c = input('Enter Salary')
            dict1[i] = {i:{'EmpID':a,'EmpName':b,'Salary':c}}

print(dict1[i])
```

I expect all the employee's details to be displayed not only the updated one

Comment: Note that the issue here is not that the dictionary is getting updated during user input, but that you are simply printing out the result wrong.

Comment: The alignment is all wrong

Comment: Do not spam inapplicable tags

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display all employees at the end, replace your last line: `print(dict1)`

Note that Python does not have block scoping, so the `i` in the last line resolves to one less than whatever value the user input for `m`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, replace `print(dict1[i]` to `print(dict1)`